# ApexPages CurrentPage getParameters is different in Salesforce1. How can I read the parameters?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-platform

I have an apex extension and VF page, as an override to the New link on a custom object, that does something I would think is pretty standard. For a new record, it checks the RecordType coming in from the URL and returns a different view depending on the record type. Conceptually, like

```
if (ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') = '012....') 
    return new PageReference('SomePage');
else return new PageReference('SomeOtherPage');
```

Which is fine until I put the page into Salesforce1. Because in Salesforce1, ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters() returns a different set of values.

In normal browser UI, the map contains

```
{RecordType=012i0000001AXw6, ent=01Ii0000001oJDs, 
  retURL=/a0N/o, save_new=1, sfdc.override=1}
```

because it's just come off the record type selection page, so it has RecordType and ent.

When the same code runs In Salesforce1, I get the record type selection page, then I'm redirected to my VF, where the map looks a bit different:

```
{isdtp=p1, nonce=52409e8a3dd9f5289e71c077c88c92422940a5c34ea2585243ef3ea6119d5236,     
save_new=1, sfdc.override=1, sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://cs15.salesforce.com}
```

How can I read the URL parameters like RecordType? where are they?

Comment: If you don't have the page enabled for SF1. then I'd expect you'll likely need to create a flex page to use in it's place. Also, it almost sounds as though you could get the same functionality using either an object or global action depending on the context.

Comment: @dougchasman Any ideas how to get the URL parameters when the VF page is rendered in SF1? I want to know what RecordType was passed in by the RecordType selector